# Bamboo SonarScanner takes long before ending the task

Tags: sonarqube, bamboo, sonarqube-scan

I'm having a problem with a plugin for Bamboo named SonarQube. This plugin should scan my code and after that send the report to our SonarQube instance. This is working fine atm, the only problem is that is takes so long before the process is done, just look at the logs:

build  07-Jun-2017 23:55:46  The SonarQube Scanner has finished

build  07-Jun-2017 23:55:46  23:55:46.965  Creating a summary markdown file...

build  07-Jun-2017 23:55:46  23:55:46.98  Analysis results: https://sonarqube.tamtam.nl/dashboard/index/sonar:Hypotheker:develop

build  07-Jun-2017 23:55:46  23:55:46.98  Post-processing succeeded.

simple  08-Jun-2017 00:34:00  Finished task 'Send to Sonar' with result: Success

simple  08-Jun-2017 00:34:00  Running post build plugin 'Docker Container Cleanup'

U can see that the task 'Send to Sonar' takes 40 minutes and I hear u say "yheah you are uploading something of course it takes time". The only problem is that it is a zip of 3MB and that should not take 40 minutes to upload.

Do you guys have any idea why this is happening?

Cheers,
Jelmer

Comment: Do you have the Build Breaker plugin installed on your SonarQube instance?

Comment: No I don't, is that recommended?

Comment: No, it's not. But it might have explained this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a guess, but it's not the upload that's taking so long. Presumably you have ["Fail build when project fails configured quality gates" provisioned in the Bamboo task](https://mibexsoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SONARBAMBOO/FAQ).

If that's the case, then the upload happens fairly quickly but either your analysis report sits in queue for a while waiting to be processed or it takes a while to process (or both), and your build task is waiting for that to complete.

Comment: Dit is helaas niet het geval :(